# Regex for extracting a string between a word and new line character in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract a string which exists between a word and a new line character in a base string. For example if the base string is:

```
String s = "Info\n" 
         + "user id: 1234\n"
         + "Region: us-east-1";
```

So I want to extract the String between `user id` and the very next new line character (`\n`) to it. Extracted string should return: **1234**

How can I use a `regex` pattern to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

I tried this to extract using substring but did not succeed.

```
str.substring(str.indexOf("user id:") + 1, str.indexOf("\n"));
```

Comment: When doing the operation in a single line you retrieve the index of the first end line (which is after info). Instead, if you use two instructions you can retrieve the first endline of the string after removing everything before user id. Try: `str = str.substring(str.indexOf("user id:") + 1); str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("\n"))`

Comment: Why regex? How about iterating over all lines, check if line starts with `"user id: "`, if yes print rest of it? Something like `Scanner sc = new Scanner(yourText); while(sc.hasNextLine){String line = sc.nextLine(); if (line.startsWith("user id:"){ String data = line.substring("user id:".length()).trim(); ` here you have data you ware looking for.

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes i'll try that approach and see.

Comment: BTW last line will probably not have `\n` after it which may cause some problems with `indexOf("\n")`.

Comment: @Pshemo i'm literally hard coding the \n here, where as in the actual scenario there'll be a line break in the base string.

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes This returns "ser id: 1234" for me.

Comment: ```String result = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1, str.indexOf("R")); while(Character.isWhitespace(result.charAt(result.length() - 1))){result = result.substring(0, text.length() - 1);} while(Character.isWhitespace(result.charAt(0))){result= result.substring(1, result.length());}```

Comment: @OP assuming that your String always procedes "user id:" and percedes "Region", this code will work. The two whiles are there to remove Whitespace from the front and end of the String.

Comment: @Kulasangar You need to first match the "user id:" and get the substring removing the characters of "user id". Then you need to remove everything after the end line. Try this code: `String s = "Info\n" + "user id: 1234\n" + "Region: us-east-1";
        String tag = "user id: ";
        s = s.substring(s.indexOf(tag) + tag.length());
        s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('\n'));`

Comment: Honestly kind of annoying that this was closed while multiple people were willing to help him come up with the specific regex to be used here. I agree that it's a duplicate, but still people were willing to help for the moment and now we have to answer with these terribly formatted code comments.

Comment: @yur thanks for the support. Yeah i was quite new to regex and was trying multiple things. But couldn't make it work. That's why I ended up asking it here.

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes alright sure. will give it a go now and get back.

Comment: I totally agree with @yur . The solutions provided on the related post are generic and for experienced users while this question was much more specific. Closing it only makes harder to help.

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes worked for me. :)

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes thanks.

Comment: @yur thanks a bunch.